# Characteristic polynomials and finding a certain Transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra

So I need help understanding a solution on a practice quiz I have.

[image]

Here is the question, the above results are explained below.

[image]

So I get the logic behind how they set up to find the solution by setting that characteristic polynomial equal to zero. Why do they want the trace to be zero and why do they need the det to be -1.

I keep trying to find eigenvalues for $A_1$ and $A_2$ but am having trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a $2 \times 2$ matrix, the characteristic polynomial is
$$ (t-\lambda_1)(t-\lambda_2) = t^2-(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)t + \lambda_1\lambda_2 $$
It happens that the trace is the sum of the eigenvalues (think of Jordan Normal Form, for example), and the determinant is the product of the eigenvalues (again, JNF). Thus for a $2 \times 2$ matrix $A$, the characteristic polynomial can be written as
$$ t^2- (\operatorname{tr}{A}) t + (\det{A}) $$
You can read off the characteristic polynomial of $A_1$ using this, which is the answer given, $t^2-t-1$. The eigenvalues are not really relevant to this problem, but they are the roots of this polynomial, which happen to be $\frac{1 \pm \sqrt{5} }{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Say that
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}.
$$
is any $2 \times 2$ matrix.  Now calculate the characteristic polynomial:
$$
\begin{align}
p_A(\lambda) &= \det (A - \lambda I) \\
&= \det \Biggl( \! \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} 
- \lambda \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \! \Biggr) \\
&= \det \begin{pmatrix} a - \lambda & b \\ c & d - \lambda \end{pmatrix} \\
&= (a - \lambda)(d - \lambda) - bc \\
&= ad - a\lambda - d\lambda + \lambda^2 - bc \\
&= \lambda^2 - (a + d)\lambda + (ad - bc) \\
&= \lambda^2 - (\operatorname{tr} A)\lambda + (\det A),
\end{align}
$$
so the linear coefficient is $-\operatorname{tr} A$ and the constant coefficient is $\det A$.

Answer (score 0):

let the eigenvalues be $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$

then the characteristic polynomial is ...

$(\lambda - \lambda_1)(\lambda - \lambda_2)= \lambda^2-(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)\lambda + \lambda_1\lambda_2 $

comparing with $ \lambda^2-\lambda - 1 $

we see that $\lambda_1+\lambda_2 = 1$  and $\lambda_1\lambda_2 = -1$

$\lambda_1+\lambda_2 $  is the trace and $\lambda_1\lambda_2$ the determinant.